# Display Day of the Week dynamically in Arrowhead TimeStamp on Hover

Tags: pine-script

Currently 'Day' is not displayed in timestamp of the Arrowhead when hovered on a particular bar  .

[image]

***str.format()*** does provide this function but the barindex has to be specified separately in code (and isn't recognised on hover).([here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Time.html#id17))

In PineScript is there a way to modify the arrowhead timestamp and show the Day (on hover)?

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. It would indeed be nice to have more flexible ways to specify the date/time format. We logged a suggestion for the chart team.

Answer (score 1):

No, the date format only supports combinations of day/month/year.

[image]

If you are looking for a way to display the day of the week on your chart, a workaround might be displaying it in a table.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_get_day() =>
    switch dayofweek
        1 => "Sunday"
        2 => "Monday"
        3 => "Tuesday"
        4 => "Wednesday"
        5 => "Thursday"
        6 => "Friday"
        7 => "Saturday"

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = f_get_day())
```

Comment: DAY of the Week has to be displayed when hovered up on 'ANY' bar (and not only the last one).The main issue here is that the arrowhead does not directly access the barindex on hovering on it.Also str.format()  supports DAY format - [Formatting dates and time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Time.html#id17).